# GKBehaviour in xcode 8 beta 4 makes gkagent position crazy

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, tvos, gameplay-kit

So I'm creating a game where I want to add some `GKGoal` for my `GKAgent` behaviour.

So after hours of fighting, I've downloaded next project this time is from Apple [Agents Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AgentsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html), and in Xcode 7.3 it works. I rewrite it to Swift and create basic GKAgent with `GKGoal(toWander:)` this is my code:

```
 class AAPLAgentNode: SKNode, GKAgentDelegate {
    init(withScene scene:SKScene ,radius: Float, position:CGPoint) {
        super.init()
        
        self.position = position
        self.zPosition = 10
        scene.addChild(self)
        
        agent = GKAgent2D()
        agent.radius = radius
        agent.position = vector2(Float(position.x), Float(position.y))
        agent.delegate = self
        agent.maxSpeed = 100
        agent.maxAcceleration = 50
        
        let circleShape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(radius))
        circleShape.lineWidth = 2.5
        circleShape.fillColor = SKColor.gray
        circleShape.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(circleShape)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    func agentWillUpdate(_ agent: GKAgent) {
        
    }
    
    func agentDidUpdate(_ agent: GKAgent) {
        self.position = CGPoint(x: Double(self.agent.position.x), y: Double(self.agent.position.y))
        print("aaa == \(self.position)")
    }
    
    var agent: GKAgent2D!
}
```

When I add to scene

```
     let wanderer = AAPLAgentNode(withScene: self, radius: 100, position: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    
    wanderer.agent.behavior = GKBehavior(goal: GKGoal(toWander: 10), weight: 100)

    agentSystem.addComponent(wanderer.agent)
```

without behaviour position is static but when I add it, position goes crazy and in each iteration of update, values are like

- position == (-10051366.0, 251672512.0)
- position == (1368370.0, 259904576.0)
- position == (-131583.0, 264841120.0)

Is it just an Xcode 8 beta bug, or am I doing something wrong. I spend a lot of hours trying to work it out.
Thanks:)

Comment: I am getting a similar behaviour (no pun intended) with Swift Playgrounds 1.1.2 on iPad with `x` position being ok, but `y` always getting meaningless huge values. There is definitely a bug in `GKGoal` implementation.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour in Xcode 9. As soon as you set a behaviour on a GKAgent2D that's a component of an SKNode, the agent's delegate method reports insane positions for the agent. This effectively renders it makes GKGoal, GKBehaviour, GKAgent inoperable in SpriteKit. Interestingly though, I don't see this behaviour with GKAgent3D attached to SCNNodes in SceneKit. Terrible that a bug as bad as this has made it through two versions of Xcode.

Comment: The same code works on iOS 11 though. I just see the erratic behaviour on macOS Sierra (haven't updated to High Sierra yet). If it's been fixed in iOS 11, perhaps it's fixed in High Sierra?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old, but are you calling with a very high deltaTime on your first update?

I was calling with the system time as my first update call to the agent behaviour, causing a massive jump at the first timestep

Comment: This was the cause. The initial value for the previousTime was 0. This was causing a massive initial value. Changing the previousTime to an optional and using the current time when nil did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's been super frustrating trying to grock this Agent, Behaviour stuff... I was having this issue in Xcode 9.0 while trying out `toSeekAgent` when I was adding my nodes and agents in the `didMove()` method of my SKScene but after "init-ing" them from `touchesBegan()` the extreme position issue went away.

Comment: This is what happened to me too, so I tried your solution and it works. I have no idea why it doesn't work in didMove() but works in touchesBegan().